# How to write a SOQL for a salesforce report

Tags: soql

[image]

How do I get the SOQL query  for this report?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to get the SOQL automatically generated for you.  It is entirely possible that a given report cannot be represented by a single SOQL query.

Here are some ideas.

1. Analyze the report and determine what a SOQL query or multiple SOQL queries with Apex to process and combine their results would be.
2. Use the Analytics API to run the report and analyze the results. The Analytics API is available [via Apex](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_analytics_intro.htm) as well as [via REST](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/index.htm).